# how to read an image and draw it into accelerated image in C++?

Tags: c++, image-processing

i wanna read an image from my computer and store it in my c++ program. i have some experience in java image processing but totally no idea how to do it in c++. i wanna achieve what the java code below does in c++:

BufferedImage sourceImage = null;

```
 try {
        // The ClassLoader.getResource() ensures we get the sprite

        // from the appropriate place, this helps with deploying the game

        // with things like webstart. You could equally do a file look

        // up here.

        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(ref);

        if (url == null) {
            fail("Can't find ref: "+ref);
        }

        // use ImageIO to read the image in

        sourceImage = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail("Failed to load: "+ref);
    }

    // create an accelerated image of the right size to store our sprite in

    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    Image image = gc.createCompatibleImage(sourceImage.getWidth(),sourceImage.getHeight(),Transparency.BITMASK);

    // draw our source image into the accelerated image

    image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage,0,0,null);

    // create a sprite, add it the cache then return it

    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(image);
    sprites.put(ref,sprite);

    return sprite;
```

Anyone can give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What environment are you getting these images in?  .NET, native Windows, Linux?  .NET has a built-in image library (System.Image).  Other environments offer different, and several, alternatives.

Comment: @MikeC i implement it in VS2010. i'm new to c++ and dont know what alternatives i can use in c++

Comment: In Win32 GDI Function , http://www.christian-etter.de/?p=283

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome) library if you want to work with your image as matrix.
This library provides a simple interface of image loading and storing, but it's main application is image processing and computer vision. So it can be an "artillery against a bird".